# Inheritance with different generic signature

Tags: javascript, typescript

i've got issue how to implement array of classes with the same functionality

here is the got which gives me an error

```
interface I<T> {

}

class A<T> implements I<T> {

    constructor () {

    }
}

class B implements I<number> {
    constructor () {

    }
}

class C<T> implements I<T> {


    private arrr: I<T> [] = [];

    constructor () {
        this.arrr.push(new A<T>());
        this.arrr.push(new B());
    }

}
```

it gives me error *`Type is not assignable to type I<T>`* on the line *         `this.arrr.push(new B());`*

how can i solve it ? i'm using Typescript 1.8

Comment: where do you get the error?

Comment: @iberbeu, i updated question

Comment: Well `T` and `number` might not be compatible

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable of a specific type, you store only those values in that variable which are of that specific type. If you declare a variable of generic type, you can only store values which are of generic type(not specific type).

In your specific case, you are declaring this.arrr as the generic type and one of the value ( new B()) you are storing in it is of a specific type. Because of this specific type value, it is throwing an error.

Sample Code

```
interface I<T> {

}

class A<T> implements I<T> {

    constructor () {

    }
}

class B<T> implements I<T> {
    constructor () {

    }
}

class C<T> implements I<T> {


    private arrr: I<T> [] = [];

    constructor () {
        this.arrr.push(new A<T>());
        this.arrr.push(new B<T>());
    }

}
```

See if it helps